# Most reliable way to extract strings between two delimiters

Tags: php, regex

I've tried multiple functions to extract whatever between two strings, The delimiters might contain special characters, I guess that's why none worked for me.

My current function:

```
function between($str, $startTag, $endTag){
    $delimiter = '#';
    $regex = $delimiter . preg_quote($startTag, $delimiter) 
                        . '(.*?)' 
                        . preg_quote($endTag, $delimiter) 
                        . $delimiter 
                        . 's';
    preg_match($regex, $str, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

Example of string:

```
#{ST@RT}#
Text i want
#{END}#

#{ST@RT}#
Second text i want
#{END}#
```

How to improve that or suggest another solution to:

- Support any kind of character or new lines
- Extract multiple strings if found

---

***Current Behavior:** Only returns the first match, And also returns the match plus the surrounding tags which is unwanted*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `m` option for multi-line regular expressions (it allows the `.` character to match newlines):

```
preg_match('/foo.+bar/m', $str);
//                    ^--- this
```

Use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get your multiple strings:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
return $matches[1]; // an array of the strings
```

**Edit:**

The reason your current code returns the match plus the surrounding tags is because you're using `return $matches`.  The `$matches` array has several elements in it.  Index `0` is always the entire string that matched the expression.  Indexes `1` and higher are your capture groups.  In your expression, you had only one capture group (the "string"), so you would have wanted to only do `return $matches[1]` instead of `return $matches`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match_all to extract multiple strings, besides that your code seems simple enough, normally simpler is faster.